# Compilation error with %hi() and %lo() with inline assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have below in-line assembly code. I am getting a compilation error "error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter" at each line where %hi, %lo present.

```
void func()
{

  __asm__ (
  "lis %%r4, %hi(%0);"
  "ori %%r4,%%r4,%lo(%0);"
  "stw r3, 0(%%r4);"
  "lis %%r4, %hi(%0);"
  "ori %%r4,%%r4,%lo(%0);"
  "lis %%r3, %hi(%1);"
  "ori %%r3,%%r3,%lo(%1);"
  "stw %%r3, 0(%%r4);"
  ::"r"(var1), "r"(var2));
}
```

On further analysis i found that inline assembly expects a number(%0, %1...) whenever it finds a % symbol. So changed all % to %%(its just a blind shot), then ended up in getting many like the one shown below.

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:3394: Error: bad expression
{standard input}:3394: Error: syntax error; found `h', expected `,'
{standard input}:3394: Error: junk at end of line: `hi(%r9)'
{standard input}:3394: Error: bad expression
{standard input}:3394: Error: syntax error; found `l', expected `,'
{standard input}:3394: Error: junk at end of line: `lo(%r9)'
{standard input}:3394: Error: bad expression
```

after a lot of efforts i came to know that there is some problem if we use %hi() or %lo in inline assembly code. If i remove %hi and %lo from my code its getting compiled. Can anyone suggest me how to use %hi() and %lo inside a inline assembly code?

Comment: Oops, I see you tried doubling the % signs. Look at the generated asm code then,using `gcc -S`. PS: your code is at least missing the clobber list.

Comment: @Jester Its just a blind try. All i want to do is to use %hi() and %lo in my assembly code. I think clobber list is optional parameter, so i didnt used it.

Comment: You shoudl use it anyway. It is there for a very good reason. Think of the function being inlined by the compiler when optimizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU AS does not support `%hi()` and `%lo()`. Instead, it uses `@h` and `@l` suffixes on the symbols to denote the high and low parts. Also note you can't use that with register operands, and you used `r` constraint.

Comment: I have tried that option and got below error {standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:3394: Error: syntax error; found `@', expected `,'
{standard input}:3394: Error: junk at end of line: `@h'. Also can you elaborate on register operands that you were mentioning in the code.

Comment: You used the `r` constraint so the compiler places your inputs into registers, but you can't use `@h/l` with registers, just as you can't use `%hi/lo` either. if you use registers, the compiler already loads the full address, so you don't need to mess with `lis/ori` yourself.

Comment: Then how to provide the input?

Comment: Try using `m` instead.

Comment: what is meant by "u", i just saw it in some document and used, it worked. Do you know about it?

Comment: I don't see `u` mentioned anywhere. There is `U` (upper case) and even that is defined as _System V Release 4 small data area reference_.

Comment: what about "g" or if you can give any pointers to reference would be fine.

Comment: `g` is bad because that may be a register too. See the manual for [simple constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) and [ppc specific constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).  In normal code, you'd just use `r` or `m` and not mess with the `lis/ori` ... leave that to the compiler.